How to prevent auto mounting of a ReFS volume in macOS Sequoia?
I have a macOS/Windows-bootable Mac Pro. Two internal HDDs form a mirror disk formatted in ReFS. How do I prevent macOS Sequoia from nagging me to initialize/eject/ignore those two HDDs each time I start up the machine under macOS?
I understand I can do that by adding the /etc/fstab file in the following format:
UUID=F21AD81B-B114-456C-B2A0-BF4452E4842D none auto rw,noauto
However, I cannot find the volume UUIDs of those two unmounted HDDs in Sequoia. (Disk Utility only shows the volume UUID of mounted disks.) Here is what diskutil info gives me on one of those two HDDs:
   Device Node:               /dev/disk7
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk7
   Device / Media Name:       ST22000NM001E-3HM103

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  SATA
   SMART Status:              Verified

   Disk Size:                 22.0 TB (22000969973760 Bytes) (exactly 42970644480 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Media OS Use Only:         No
   Media Read-Only:           No
   Volume Read-Only:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               No
   Virtual:                   No
   Hardware AES Support:      No
   Device Location:           "SATA2"


A UUID is an attribute of an APFS or HFS volume. macOS sees these drives as uninitialized, so they don't have a UUID or any other property by which they can be uniquely identified. The only way to stop the prompts would be to disable Disk Arbitration completely. There is a tool that purports to do that: https://github.com/aburgh/Disk-Arbitrator

Disk Arbitrator does not solve the problem: The Initialize/Eject/Ignore dialog boxes for the HDDs pop up before Disk Arbitrator starts up among login items.

I don't recommend this action, but if it's important enough to you to suppress those prompts at the cost of disabling a system component, you can try this at your own risk:
sudo launchctl disable system/com.apple.diskarbitrationd

I haven't tried it, I don't know of anyone who has, and I don't know what will happen. Although I consider this bad advice, I think you're entitled to do as you see fit with your own computer. Back up all data first.
If there is no immediate effect, kill diskarbitrationd. It should not restart.
To revert:
sudo launchctl enable system/com.apple.diskarbitrationd

If this action does what I expect it to, there will be no more automounting of any external volumes. You'll have to mount them manually in Disk Utility or in the shell, every time. Much more inconvenient that what you have to do now, in my opinion, but it's your call.

I agree this cure very much looks worse than the disease. But thanks anyway.
